# Should I have a layer in between my controller and model in Node-Express app?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, model-view-controller, sequelize.js

I have an Express application where I use Sequelize to interact with my MySQL database. The models just represent the database tables with corresponding fields,  without containing any additional logic. I want my controllers to not be fat and for that I think I should have a layer in between which contains all of the logic and which uses the model to interact with the database.

Is this a good practice and if it is what should I call this layer and what exactly should it contain?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, great question.

Second of all, this is how I would do it:

in your models, say you have a user model, users.js.

In that model for your user/db interface, after your

`const User = module.exports = <sql declaration and model reference>;`

you can create other module exports like this:

```
module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    <Sequelize logic goes here>
};
```

And this is essentially middleware/controller for your model class for handling routines.

You might use this by importing your user model and then calling your exported module:

`const User = require("../models/users")`

and then when it's time to call your function:

```
User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
    <some logic with regard to your user>
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your sequelize models and instances with methods and hooks, your controllers would ideally only make a few calls to these methods.

For instance, you could add something like this to your User model:

```
instanceMethods: {

    encryptPassword: function(plainPassword) { 

        if(!this.salt){
            this.salt = randomString.generate(10);
        }

        var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', this.salt);
        cipher.update(plainPassword, 'utf8', 'base64');
        var encryptedPassword = cipher.final('base64')
        return encryptedPassword;
    },

    decryptPassword: function(){
        var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc', this.salt);
        decipher.update(this.password, 'base64', 'utf8');
        var decryptedPassword = decipher.final('utf8');
        return decryptedPassword;
    }
}
```

And maybe even add a pre-save hook to check if the user is new and then encrypt the password before saving, you could create authentication methods to call this from your model and not your controller, and so on...